# Extend from UserModel of Django and use it to login

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

I need to create an authentication method for use `is_authenticated()` and other methods from my templates. The problem is that I didn´t understand the django documentation.

I have my User model and I wish to use it like the User model (like django uses its own model).

What should I do? Who can guide me? Thanks!

Comment: What documentation did you read?

Comment: The topic on *Custom authentication* is quite comprehenseive: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/

Answer (score 0):

You must add a foreign key fields which refers to User class of Django.

Example :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class yourUserModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=True)

    def your_authenticated_method():
        self.user.is_authenticated()
```

I hope that I answered well at your question